# Are there solutions to $a=\frac{2b^3+2c^3+d^3}{2b^2+2c^2+d^2}$ in positive integers $(a,b,c,d)$ with $d>1$?

Tags: number-theory

Let be $a, b, c, d$ positive integers.
Consider the following equation:

$$a=\frac{2b^3+2c^3+d^3}{2b^2+2c^2+d^2}$$

$(a,b,c,d)=(1,1,1,1)$ is a solution
$(a,b,c,d)=(5,4,6,1)$ is another solution.

> Are there integer solutions with $d>1$?

Comment: @Peter can these solutions be found only by the brute force of a computer?

Comment: $(2, 2, 2, 2)$ is also a solution where $d>1$.

Comment: (5,4,6,1) is not a solution

Answer (score 1):

It seems that $\frac{2b^3+2c^3+d^3}{2b^2+2c^2+d^2}$ is not equal to 5 when $b=4$, $c=6$ and $d=1$, no ?

Brute-forcing can help you to get some solutions :

```
(1,1,1,1)
(2,2,2,2)
(3,2,2,4)
(3,3,3,3)
(5,3,5,6)
(8,3,9,6)
(4,4,4,4)
(6,4,4,8)
(5,5,3,6)
(5,5,5,5)
(6,6,6,6)
(7,7,7,7)
(8,7,9,4)
(8,8,8,8)
(8,9,3,6)
(8,9,7,4)
(9,9,9,9)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let $b=c=d=t$. The expression simplifies to $a=t$. Hence, you can get many solutions where $d>1$.

Answer (score 0):

I get it now. Begin with any triple such that $\gcd(b,c,d) = 1.$ The fraction is not necessarily an integer. However, there is a smallest multiplier, call it $k,$ such that using $(kb,kc,kd)$ does give integer $a,$ also $\gcd(a, kb,kc,kd) = 1.$ Also, the algorithm to find $k$ is easy. 
$$ k = \frac{2b^2+2c^2+d^2}{\gcd \left( 2b^2+2c^2+d^2 \;, \;2b^3+2c^3+d^3 \right)} $$

In particular, the mistaken triple (6,4,1) must be multiplied by 35 to get $a$ integral.

```
original     6   4   1 mult    35 gives      187       210     140      35
```

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./mse 
original     1   1   1 mult     1 gives        1         1       1       1
original     1   1   2 mult     2 gives        3         2       2       4
original     1   1   3 mult    13 gives       31        13      13      39
original     1   1   4 mult     5 gives       17         5       5      20
original     1   1   5 mult    29 gives      129        29      29     145
original     1   1   6 mult     2 gives       11         2       2      12
original     2   1   1 mult    11 gives       19        22      11      11
original     2   1   2 mult     7 gives       13        14       7      14
original     2   1   3 mult    19 gives       45        38      19      57
original     2   1   4 mult    13 gives       41        26      13      52
original     2   1   5 mult    35 gives      143        70      35     175
original     2   1   6 mult    23 gives      117        46      23     138
original     2   2   1 mult    17 gives       33        34      34      17
original     2   2   3 mult    25 gives       59        50      50      75
original     2   2   5 mult    41 gives      157        82      82     205
original     3   1   1 mult     7 gives       19        21       7       7
original     3   1   2 mult     3 gives        8         9       3       6
original     3   1   3 mult    29 gives       83        87      29      87
original     3   1   4 mult     3 gives       10         9       3      12
original     3   1   5 mult    45 gives      181       135      45     225
original     3   1   6 mult     7 gives       34        21       7      42
original     3   2   1 mult    27 gives       71        81      54      27
original     3   2   2 mult     5 gives       13        15      10      10
original     3   2   3 mult    35 gives       97       105      70     105
original     3   2   4 mult    21 gives       67        63      42      84
original     3   2   5 mult    17 gives       65        51      34      85
original     3   2   6 mult    31 gives      143        93      62     186
original     3   3   1 mult    37 gives      109       111     111      37
original     3   3   2 mult    10 gives       29        30      30      20
original     3   3   4 mult    13 gives       43        39      39      52
original     3   3   5 mult    61 gives      233       183     183     305
original     4   1   1 mult    35 gives      131       140      35      35
original     4   1   2 mult    19 gives       69        76      19      38
original     4   1   3 mult    43 gives      157       172      43     129
original     4   1   4 mult    25 gives       97       100      25     100
original     4   1   5 mult    59 gives      255       236      59     295
original     4   1   6 mult    35 gives      173       140      35     210
original     4   2   1 mult    41 gives      145       164      82      41
original     4   2   3 mult    49 gives      171       196      98     147
original     4   2   5 mult    65 gives      269       260     130     325
original     4   3   1 mult    17 gives       61        68      51      17
original     4   3   2 mult    27 gives       95       108      81      54
original     4   3   3 mult    59 gives      209       236     177     177
original     4   3   4 mult    11 gives       41        44      33      44
original     4   3   5 mult    75 gives      307       300     225     375
original     4   3   6 mult    43 gives      199       172     129     258
original     4   4   1 mult    65 gives      257       260     260      65
original     4   4   3 mult    73 gives      283       292     292     219
original     4   4   5 mult    89 gives      381       356     356     445
original     5   1   1 mult    53 gives      253       265      53      53
original     5   1   2 mult    14 gives       65        70      14      28
original     5   1   3 mult    61 gives      279       305      61     183
original     5   1   4 mult    17 gives       79        85      17      68
original     5   1   5 mult    77 gives      377       385      77     385
original     5   1   6 mult    22 gives      117       110      22     132
original     5   2   1 mult    59 gives      267       295     118      59
original     5   2   2 mult    31 gives      137       155      62      62
original     5   2   3 mult    67 gives      293       335     134     201
original     5   2   4 mult    37 gives      165       185      74     148
original     5   2   5 mult    83 gives      391       415     166     415
original     5   2   6 mult    47 gives      241       235      94     282
original     5   3   1 mult    69 gives      305       345     207      69
original     5   3   2 mult     3 gives       13        15       9       6
original     5   3   3 mult    77 gives      331       385     231     231
original     5   3   4 mult    21 gives       92       105      63      84
original     5   3   5 mult    31 gives      143       155      93     155
original     5   3   6 mult     1 gives        5         5       3       6
original     5   4   1 mult    83 gives      379       415     332      83
original     5   4   2 mult    43 gives      193       215     172      86
original     5   4   3 mult    91 gives      405       455     364     273
original     5   4   4 mult    49 gives      221       245     196     196
original     5   4   5 mult   107 gives      503       535     428     535
original     5   4   6 mult    59 gives      297       295     236     354
original     5   5   1 mult   101 gives      501       505     505     101
original     5   5   2 mult    26 gives      127       130     130      52
original     5   5   3 mult   109 gives      527       545     545     327
original     5   5   4 mult    29 gives      141       145     145     116
original     5   5   6 mult    34 gives      179       170     170     204
original     6   1   1 mult     5 gives       29        30       5       5
original     6   1   2 mult     3 gives       17        18       3       6
original     6   1   3 mult    83 gives      461       498      83     249
original     6   1   4 mult    15 gives       83        90      15      60
original     6   1   5 mult    99 gives      559       594      99     495
original     6   1   6 mult    11 gives       65        66      11      66
original     6   2   1 mult    81 gives      449       486     162      81
original     6   2   3 mult    89 gives      475       534     178     267
original     6   2   5 mult    35 gives      191       210      70     175
original     6   3   1 mult    91 gives      487       546     273      91
original     6   3   2 mult    47 gives      247       282     141      94
original     6   3   4 mult    53 gives      275       318     159     212
original     6   3   5 mult   115 gives      611       690     345     575
original     6   4   1 mult    35 gives      187       210     140      35
original     6   4   3 mult   113 gives      587       678     452     339
original     6   4   5 mult   129 gives      685       774     516     645
original     6   5   1 mult   123 gives      683       738     615     123
original     6   5   2 mult    21 gives      115       126     105      42
original     6   5   3 mult   131 gives      709       786     655     393
original     6   5   4 mult    69 gives      373       414     345     276
original     6   5   5 mult    49 gives      269       294     245     245
original     6   5   6 mult    79 gives      449       474     395     474
original     6   6   1 mult    29 gives      173       174     174      29
original     6   6   5 mult   169 gives      989      1014    1014     845
```

Answer (score 0):

For the equation.

$$a=\frac{2b^3+2c^3+d^3}{2b^2+2c^2+d^2}$$

You can record this parameterization.

$$a=p^3-3s^3$$

$$b=p^3+sp^2-9s^3$$

$$c=p(p^2-6s^2)$$

$$d=p^3-2sp^2+9s^3$$